# Diagonalizing a specific case of symmetric block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues, eigenvector, block-matrices

Let's consider the following block matrix

$$ M = \begin{pmatrix}D&A^T\\A&-D\end{pmatrix},$$

where $A$ and $D$ are $n \times n$ matrices. The diagonal matrix $D$ is defined by $D_{kk} = k \alpha$, where $\alpha \in \Bbb C$. Is there a simple link between the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of the block matrix $M$ and $A$ and $D$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_determinant

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3413454/339790)

Comment: Have you tried the case where $n=1$?